# selecting cell as part of the code to execute

Tags: excel, vba, loops, pdf, text-files

I am trying to convert a list of pdf in excel into text. I have already have both filename listed in 2 columns. All I need now is to make sure the code below reads both `sfile` and `dfile` from the cell so that the code can execute and thereafter looping to convert all the files in the column. I am not able to correctly do it for these both lines. can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

`sfile = ws("Sheet1").rng("A" & "row").Value`
`dfile = ws("Sheet1").rng("C" & "row").Value`

```
Sub ConvertPDF()

Dim sfile As String, dfile As String
Dim AcroXApp As Acrobat.acroApp, AcroXAVDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
Dim AcroXPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc, jsObj As Object, Row As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Row = 2

sfile = ws("Sheet1").rng("A" & "row").Value
dfile = ws("Sheet1").rng("C" & "row").Value

Do While ws("Sheet1").Range("A" & "row") <> ""
Set AcroXApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
'AcroXApp.Show
Set AcroXAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
AcroXAVDoc.Open sfile, "Acrobat"
Set AcroXPDDoc = AcroXAVDoc.GetPDDoc
Set jsObj = AcroXPDDoc.GetJSObject
jsObj.SaveAs dfile, "com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text"

AcroXAVDoc.Close False
AcroXApp.Hide
AcroXApp.Exit
Loop
Row = Row + 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the cells like this

```
sfile = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Row).Value
dfile = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Row).Value
```

Using the worksheet [code name](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-tutorial-1/#The_Code_Name_of_the_Worksheet) is better

```
sfile = Sheet1.Range("A" & Row).Value
dfile = Sheet1.Range("C" & Row).Value
```